# SOLVED: Flutter: Could not find correct provoider when placing provider in main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to write a note-app as my first project in Flutter (therefore I have not much experience). I want to use a provider to pass the informations needed. When placing the `ChangeNotifierProvider` around the `Scaffold()` in my HomeScreen, it works totaly fine. However, when trying to place the `ChangeNotifierProvider` around any Widget in the `Main.dart`-file, I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<NoteData> above this Consumer<NoteData> Widdget
```

I have three files: `main.dart`, `home-screen.dart` and `note_model`. The consumer is in the `home-screen.dart`, using the needed information from `note_model.dart` to list all notes on the Homescreen.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'models/note_data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<NoteData>(
      create: (context) => NoteData(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

**home_screen.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/note_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/main.dart'

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Screen"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column( 
          children: <Widget>[
            // List of notes
            Consumer<NoteData>(
              builder: (context, provider, child){
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: provider.allNotes.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(provider.allNotes[index].text),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );     
  }
}
```

**note_data.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Note {
  late String id;
  late String text;

  Note({
    required this.id,
    required this.text,
  });
}

class NoteData extends ChangeNotifier{
  // overall list of Notes
  List<Note> allNotes = [
    Note(id: "0", text: "first Note"),
    Note(id: "string_id", text: "second Note")
  ];
}
```

To find out why this error appears, I tried wrapping the `ChangeNotifierProvider` from bottom up around every widget above the Consumer (like `Column()`, `Scaffold()`). It alsways works fine, until the `ChangeNotifierProvider` moves to the `main.dart`-file, no matter which widget. But since I want to have access to the Provider not only inside the HomeScreen, I want to wrap it around `MyApp()`.
I also tried using a `builder: (context, child) => MyApp()` function instead of a `child`-propertie, but it doesn't work eather.

EDIT:
The problems seems to be that i store the `home_screen.dart` and `note_data.dart` in separate folders inside the `lib` folder. When i place the files directly inside the `lib` folder, no error appears.

Hope anyone can help. Many Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Attached snippet is working in my case, can you try `flutter clean` & rebuild the app?

Comment: Hey, I know the problem you are facing.
Try This:
Create an object of your provider inside build function and access it by using that object.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Im coding in Browser IDE (Zapp.run). Flutter SDK version `>=2.18.2 <3.0.0`, provider version `6.0.5`. Tried the snippet in a completely new project... not working.

Comment: @Mohitjain Unfortunately this also doesn't work... same error :/

Comment: Can you try on updated version

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh The IDE doesn't allow to update the SDK. But I edited my question narrowing the problem to be because the files are stored in different folders. Maybe this helps to find an answer.

Comment: first you need to `flutter upgrade` and then you can use update version on `sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by myself:

The `imports` should work as they are, however `provider` doesn't seem to be quite happy with them, so I need to specify the whole path in the `main.dart`.

Instead of:

> import 'screens/home_screen.dart';

> import 'models/note_data.dart';

I need to  write:

> import 'package:flutter_app/screens/home_screen.dart';

> import 'package:flutter_app/models/note_data.dart';